# How to update main array in laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-5.8

I Need help on updating Main Array with its data changed in a foreach loop.
Here is my code :

```php
$query = DB::table('autostk')
    ->where('autostk.branchid', $branch_id)
    ->where('autostk.itemcode', $request->itemcode)
    ->whereDate('autostk.date', '<=', $request->tdate)
    ->where('autostk.branchid', $branch_id)
    ->leftjoin('journal', 'autostk.refno', '=', 'journal.vno')
    ->where('journal.code', '>=', 100)
    ->where('journal.branchid', $branch_id)
    ->leftjoin('accounts', 'journal.code', '=', 'accounts.code')
    ->where('accounts.branchid', $branch_id)
    ->select('journal.code', 'accounts.title', 'autostk.*')
    ->orderBY('date')->get()
    ->map(function ($item, $key) {
        return (array)$item;
    })
    ->all();

foreach ($query as $row) {
    if (is_null($row['qtyin'])) {
        $row['qtyin'] = 0;
    }
    if (is_null($row['qtyout'])) {
        $row['qtyout'] = 0;
    }
    if (is_null($row['rate'])) {
        $row['rate'] = 0;
    }
    if ($row['vtype'] = 'PI' && $row['qtyin'] > 0) {
        $stkval = ($bal * $avgrate) + ($row['qtyin'] * $row['rate']);
        if ($bal > 0) {
            $bal = $bal + $row['qtyin'] - $row['qtyout'];
            if ($bal > 0 && $stkval > 0) {
                $avgrate = $stkval / $bal;
            }
        } else {
            $bal = $bal + $row['qtyin'] - $row['qtyout'];
            $avgrate = $row['rate'];
        }
    } else {
        $bal = $bal + $row['qtyin'] - $row['qtyout'];
    }
    $row['balqty'] = $bal;
    $row['avgrate'] = $avgrate;
}
```

My question is how to update $query with changes made to $row.  I am new to php and laravel and have tried push(), put(), etc.  Don't know which function is required in this case.

Comment: If you want to add new value to an array then you can use push. Can you explain more about your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep changes you've applied to `$row` inside the foreach you just need to pass it by reference:

```
foreach ($query as &$row) { //notice the & before $row
```

Alternatively, you could could use just move the code inside your `foreach` to inside your `map` closure:

```
->map(function ($item, $key) use ($bal, $avgrate) {

    $row = (array)$item;

    if (is_null($row['qtyin'])) {
        $row['qtyin'] = 0;
    }
    if (is_null($row['qtyout'])) {
        $row['qtyout'] = 0;
    }
    if (is_null($row['rate'])) {
        $row['rate'] = 0;
    }
    if ($row['vtype'] = 'PI' && $row['qtyin'] > 0) {
        $stkval = ($bal * $avgrate) + ($row['qtyin'] * $row['rate']);
        if ($bal > 0) {
            $bal = $bal + $row['qtyin'] - $row['qtyout'];
            if ($bal > 0 && $stkval > 0) {
                $avgrate = $stkval / $bal;
            }
        } else {
            $bal = $bal + $row['qtyin'] - $row['qtyout'];
            $avgrate = $row['rate'];
        }
    } else {
        $bal = $bal + $row['qtyin'] - $row['qtyout'];
    }
    $row['balqty'] = $bal;
    $row['avgrate'] = $avgrate;

    return $row;

})
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  foreach ($query as &$row) worked nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
$query = DB::table('autostk')
    ->where('autostk.branchid', $branch_id)
    ->where('autostk.itemcode', $request->itemcode)
    ->whereDate('autostk.date', '<=', $request->tdate)
    ->where('autostk.branchid', $branch_id)
    ->leftjoin('journal', 'autostk.refno', '=', 'journal.vno')
    ->where('journal.code', '>=', 100)
    ->where('journal.branchid', $branch_id)
    ->leftjoin('accounts', 'journal.code', '=', 'accounts.code')
    ->where('accounts.branchid', $branch_id)
    ->select('journal.code', 'accounts.title', 'autostk.*')
    ->orderBY('date')->get()
    ->map(function ($item, $key) {
        return (array)$item;
    })
    ->all();

$row_data = [];
foreach ($query as $row) {
    if (is_null($row['qtyin'])) {
        $row['qtyin'] = 0;
    }
    if (is_null($row['qtyout'])) {
        $row['qtyout'] = 0;
    }
    if (is_null($row['rate'])) {
        $row['rate'] = 0;
    }
    if ($row['vtype'] = 'PI' && $row['qtyin'] > 0) {
        $stkval = ($bal * $avgrate) + ($row['qtyin'] * $row['rate']);
        if ($bal > 0) {
            $bal = $bal + $row['qtyin'] - $row['qtyout'];
            if ($bal > 0 && $stkval > 0) {
                $avgrate = $stkval / $bal;
            }
        } else {
            $bal = $bal + $row['qtyin'] - $row['qtyout'];
            $avgrate = $row['rate'];
        }
    } else {
        $bal = $bal + $row['qtyin'] - $row['qtyout'];
    }
    $row['balqty'] = $bal;
    $row['avgrate'] = $avgrate;
    $row_data[] = $row;
}
```

Now use `$row_data`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1

```
//use toArray() in last to get the result as an array
$query = ...->all()->toArray();

foreach ($query as $key => $row) {
     //inside here instead of using $row, use $query[$key]
     //so for example $row['rate'] = 0; becomes:
     $query[$key]['rate'] = 0;
}
```

#### Option 2

```
//use toArray() in last to get the result as an array
$query = ...->all()->toArray();

//use pass by reference with help of &
foreach ($query as $key => &$row) {
   ...
}
```

However, be very careful with a pass by reference approach otherwise you might run into issues if you reuse the same array.

#### Option 3

```
$query = ...->all();
foreach ($query as $key => $row) {
    //access it as object
    //instead of using $row['qtyin'] use:
    $row->qtyin = 0;
}
```

Its dealer's choice :)